# Is a curve in a 1-dimensional manifold always a geodesic for some parameterization?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Consider a curve embedded in a 1-dimensional manifold. Since the manifold itself is one-dimensional, there are no alternative curves that can be taken. Based on this observation, is it correct to say that the given curve must be a geodesic for some parameterization?

If this is not accurate, could you please point out any misconceptions or missing elements in my understanding?

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: The claim is correct but your proof does not work. You should use the actual definition of geodesics instead.

Comment: Parametrize your curve $\gamma$ by arc-length. What can you say about $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'$? Hint: differentiate the equality $\|\gamma'\|^2 = 1$.

Comment: What about $t\to t^2$, defined on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It is not an embedding